# How do I make this simple for loop faster in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop like this:

```
len = 10000
alpha_0 = seq(0, 10, length = len)

for (a in 1:len) {
    alpha0 = alpha_0[a]
    llike[a] <- llikelihood(alpha0, beta, q, d, n)
}
```

Basically I am just changing values of alpha0 and then inputting that value into a function called `llikelihood`. The `llikelihood`function looks like so:

```
llikelihood = function(alpha0, beta, q, d, n) {
  llike = n*(lgamma(alpha0) - sum_a(alpha0, beta, d) + sum_b (alpha0, beta, q, d, n))
  return(llike)
}

sum_a = function(alpha0, beta, d) {
  sum_a = 0
  for (i in 1:d) {
    sum_a = sum_a + lgamma(alpha0*beta[i]) 
  }
  return(sum_a)
}

# returns the output to summation from 1 to k of (alpha0*beta[i] - 1)*log(x_i)
sum_b = function(alpha0, beta, q, d, n) { 
  # replace zero values
  sum_b = 0
  # find the log q
  logq = log(q)
  qlog = apply(logq, 1, sum)
  #  for each column, sum up the draws
  for (i in 1:d) {
    sum_b = sum_b + (alpha0*beta[i] - 1)*1/n*qlog[i]
  }
  return(sum_b)
}
```

Is there any way I can make the whole process more efficient? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Most likely the `llikelihood` function is vectorized, so `llikelihood(alpha_0, beta, q, d, n)` should provide a vector with your intended results and without then need for the loop.

Comment: Actually, the `llikelihood` function isn't vectorized since I wrote it myself and don't know much R or linear algebra to make it more efficient. Just added some more details on the function above. Is there any way I can make the whole process a little more efficient? Many thanks!